# need advice on mysql data base storing information

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using Java EE (JDBC, MVC, DAO) and MySql.

I'm making my own project, so all architecture's design - my responsibility.

I have a system "Facultative", where i have entity Facultative, that store information about course, lecturer and start and duration.

Now, it is also storing a field "Status": Wait (not started), Started and Ended.

And this is a place, i have problem: how should information be updated?

Of course, it is possible, to give this function to the admin, but it seems to easy and not efficient.

I have idea - not store field "status" at DB, but to check what status in Model Entity (by checking start date/duration).

I'm using MVC Pattern and not sure if it is correct to add such method to Class.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really an issue of the "world" you are modeling.  Ask yourself this:

1. Do courses ever fail to start at the scheduled time?
2. Do you want to explicitly model that?

If the answer to both of those questions is "yes", then you can't treat the `status` field as derived from (just) the start and end dates (and the current date).  And similarly, automatically setting a (non-derived) `status` field based on the dates is dubious.

On the other hand ... setting the `status` administratively would be a bad idea too, since it needs to be done at a particular time; i.e. when the lecture actually starts.

But then ... actually modeling this accurately needs to acknowledge that there is a "gap" between the information in your database, and what is actually happening in the real world.  It is (probably) impractical to ensure that the database is 100% accurate.  So the *pragmatic* solution is to accept that: make it a "feature" of the system.

If you take the pragmatic view, then making `status` derived should be good enough.  (Change its name to `notional_status` or something, and change the `start` and `end` fields to `scheduled_start` and `scheduled_end` or something.)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful advice!

Answer (score 0):

Storing the start date and end date (or duration) and deriving the status makes the most sense to me.

The main advantage is the data wont need to be updated as the Status transitions from `Wait` to `Started` and `Started` to `Ended` and just take care of itself as time passes naturally.

Comment: "deriving the status" - you mean to get it from class, not db, yes?

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful advice!